# Is there any method in WSO2 EI to get the status code description from the http response

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

Is there any method in wso2 EI to get the status code names like "ok", "internal server error" etc..
Access the status name(text) not code to show in postman.

I got the status code by `$axis2:HTTP_SC`, and now I want the status code message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following property for this.

```xml
<property expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC_DESC" name="Description"/>
<property expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC" name="Code"/>
```